# Creating text items on the fly as well as producing a Rich Text Format document

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

Within Oracle ApEx 4.1 and assuming through the use of jQuery, how can I go about creating text item fields on the fly based on a drop down list, where the user is asked how many text items are required?

A basic example would be, if a user selected 3 from the drop down list, then 3 individual text fields would be presented to the user.

Another question I have then, is how would I go about saving the data in these fields to the database?

In addition to the above, based on the data stored within the database, I then need to produce a Rich Text Format based on some template - how can this be done within Oracle ApEx.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to how many items you can create? As for the RTF: i'm not sure i totally understand. What is 'some template'? Would the apex 'Rich Text Editor' item type do anything for you?

Comment: Hey Tom, from my understanding of the requirements, I believe it's maximum of 6. Are you able to assist (possibly with an example) of creating these as well as how to store and retrieve them from the DB - thanks. I will look into the Rich Text Editor item but really keen to get a handle on text item creation based on drop down list count selection. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this in several ways.
However, if you want actual page items which you can reference like `:P20_SOME_ITEM` and want to generate those on the fly: that won't work.

---

### Page items

If you know there is an upper boundary and you wish to use actual page items, then you could achieve this by putting a condition on page items.
Eg, select list with values 1 through 6. On change the page is submitted. The first item `P20_ITEM1` is always displayed. The second item `P20_ITEM2` has a condition on it, of type `SQL Expression`:

```
:P20_AMOUNT>1
```

You can then apply the same condition to the other items: `:P20_AMOUNT>2`, `>3`,...

---

### Item array

The alternative way is still using text inputs, but not referenced by a bind variable. You can apply the same logic as that is used in tabular forms: use an item array. 
You can still go about that in several ways:

**(1)** Eg: Create an actual manual tabular form
Classic report, source:

```
select apex_item.text(1, null) some_item
from dual
connect by level <= :P20_AMOUNT
```

Make the column a Standard report column. 
You won't have an addrow button, but since the first row will always be there, you can clone the row.

```
function addRows(){
   var lAmount = $("#P20_AMOUNT").val(),
       lTbody = $("#report_tabform tbody.uReportBody table tbody"),
       lInitRow = $("tr:first", lTbody);
   for(var i=1;i<lAmount;i++){
      lTbody.append(lInitRow.clone());
   };
};
```

This is a selector for theme 23 (Crimson), so you may need to adapt this. It will clone the first row and append it x times. You can call this function in a button for example.

**(2)** Create a plsql region
You could output the required HTML through a PLSQL region too of course.

```
FOR i IN 1..:P20_AMOUNT
LOOP
   htp.p('<input type="text" name="f01" />');
END LOOP;
```

This too would require a submit of the page after the amount selection changes.

**(3)** Or use javascript to create everything:

```
//with empty region as basis
//pNode: node which will hold the generated table
//pName: name of the item array (f01, f02,...)
//pAmount: amount of items to be generated
function generateItemArray(pNode, pName, pAmount){
   var lTable = $('<table></table>'), 
       lRow = $('<tr></tr>'), 
       lCell = $('<td></td>'),
       lInput = $('<input name="'+pName+'" type="text" />'),
       lnRow, lnInput;
   //ln vars: will hold cloned items
   //cloning is necessary because the same instance can not be
   //put in multiple places
   for(var i=1;i<=pAmount;i++){
      lnRow = lRow.clone(); //new row
      lnRow.append(lCell.clone().text("Text for item "+i)); //first cell: label
      lnRow.append(lCell.clone().append(lInput.clone())); //second cell: input item
      lTable.append(lnRow); //append the row to the table
   };

   pNode.html(lTable);  //replace node contents with new table
   // or use append - but you may want to clear the previous content
   // Best use would be to provide a container which you know will only
   // contain the generated items.
};
```

This won't require a submit when the amount changes. You can do this dynamically by binding to the onchange event of the select list.

**--->**
In these 3 cases you can then access the submmitted values through their associated array. For example, consider this After Submit process:

```
for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count
loop
   apex_debug_message.log_message('item value: '||apex_application.g_f01(i));
end loop;
```

This will send the values to the debug output when you run the page in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your possible solutions - will investigate and let you know.

Comment: Hi Tom, just thought I'd touch base with you and let you know that I have decided to go the Javascript method. Once again Tom, I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Glad i could! Just a quick note: don't forget that on tabular forms the item arrays are also used by default and that this could conflict on such a page when the same array is used. Easily solved of course by changing the array.